# Implementing Inheritance - can't get a method working, though similar methods in my code work fine

Tags: java

Here is my code:

**OrderListTest**

```
package orderlisttest;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class OrderListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer orderListSize = Input.getInteger("order list size: ");
        OrderList orders = new OrderList(orderListSize);
        Integer orderNumber;
        Integer option;
        do {
            System.out.println("0: quit");
            System.out.println("1: add order");
            System.out.println("2: deliver order");
            System.out.println("3: refund order");
            System.out.println("4: pay order");
            System.out.println("5: display unpaid credit orders");
            System.out.println("6: display orders");
            option = Input.getInteger("option: ");
            switch (option) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("quitting program");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("1: credit order");
                    System.out.println("2: cash order");
                    Integer type = Input.getInteger("order type: ");
                    Integer number = Input.getInteger("number: ");
                    Integer value = Input.getInteger("value");
                    if (type == 1) {
                        try {
                            System.out.print("Paid? y/n");
                            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String input = scan.nextLine();
                            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                                orderNumber = selectOrder(orders);
                                orders.payOrder(orderNumber);
                                System.out.println("Paid");
                            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                                System.out.println("Not paid");
                            }

                        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid input!");
                        }
                        orders.addCreditOrder(number, value);
                    } else {
                        Boolean discountApplied = true;
                        orders.addCashOrder(number, value, discountApplied);
                    }

                    break;
                case 2:
                    orderNumber = selectOrder(orders);
                    orders.deliverOrder(orderNumber);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    orderNumber = selectOrder(orders);
                    orders.refundOrder(orderNumber);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    orderNumber = selectOrder(orders);
                    orders.payOrder(orderNumber);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    // self assessment 7 add code here

                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println(orders);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("invalid option");
            }
        } while (option != 0);
    }

    private static Integer selectOrder(OrderList orders) {
        Integer order;
        System.out.println(orders);
        order = Input.getInteger("order: ");
        return order;
    }
}
```

**OrderList**

```
package orderlisttest;

public class OrderList {

    private Order[] orders;
    private Integer numberOfOrders;
    private Integer number;

    public OrderList(Integer orderListSize) {
        this.orders = new Order[orderListSize];
        this.numberOfOrders = 0;
        this.number = 1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String orderListDetails = new String();
        if (this.numberOfOrders != 0) {
            orderListDetails += String.format("%-10s%-10s%10s%15s%15s%15s%15s\n", 
                    "NUMBER", "TYPE", "VALUE", "DELIVERED", "REFUNDED", "DISCOUNTED", "PAID");
            for (Integer order = 0; order < this.numberOfOrders; order++) {
                orderListDetails += this.orders[order] + "\n";
            }
        } else {
            orderListDetails += "order list is empty";
        }
        return orderListDetails;
    }

    public void addCreditOrder(Integer number, Integer value) {
        this.orders[this.numberOfOrders] = new CreditOrder(number, value);
        this.numberOfOrders++;
    }

    public void addCashOrder(Integer number, Integer value, Boolean discountApplied) {
        this.orders[this.numberOfOrders] = new CashOrder(number, value, discountApplied);
        this.numberOfOrders++;
    }

    public void deliverOrder(Integer number) {
        Order order = this.getOrder(number);
        order.deliverOrder();
    }

    public void refundOrder(Integer number) {
        Order order = this.getOrder(number);
        order.refundOrder();
    }

    public void payOrder(Integer number) {
        Order order = this.getOrder(number);
        order.payOrder();
    }

    private Order getOrder(Integer number) {
        Order order = null;
        Integer index = 0;
        while (order == null) {
            if (number.equals(this.orders[index].getNumber())) {
                order = this.orders[index];
            } else {
                index++;
            }
        }
        return order;
    }
    // self assessment 7 add code here
}
```

**Order**

```
package orderlisttest;

public abstract class Order {

    private Integer number;
    protected Integer value;
    private Boolean delivered;
    protected Boolean paid;
    protected Boolean refunded;

    public Order(Integer number, Integer value) {
        this.number = number;
        this.value = value;
        this.delivered = false;
        this.paid = false;
        this.refunded = false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String orderDetails = new String();
        orderDetails += String.format("%-10d", this.number);
        if (this instanceof CashOrder) {
            orderDetails += String.format("%-10s", "Cash");
        } else {
            orderDetails += String.format("%-10s", "Credit");
        }
        orderDetails += String.format("%10d%15s%15s", this.value, this.delivered.toString(), this.refunded.toString());
        return orderDetails;
    }

    public abstract void refund();

    public void deliverOrder() {
        this.delivered = true;
    }

    public void refundOrder() {
        this.refunded = true;
    }

    public void payOrder() {
        this.paid = true;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

}
```

**CashOrder**

```
package orderlisttest;

public class CashOrder extends Order {

    private Boolean discountApplied;

    public CashOrder(Integer number, Integer value, Boolean discountApplied) {
        super(number, value);
        this.discountApplied = discountApplied;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String cashOrderDetails = new String();
        cashOrderDetails += super.toString();
        cashOrderDetails += String.format("%15s", this.discountApplied.toString());
        return cashOrderDetails;
    }

    public void refund() {
        this.refunded = true;
    }
}
```

**CreditOrder**

```
package orderlisttest;

public class CreditOrder extends Order {

    private Boolean paid;

    public CreditOrder(Integer number, Integer value) {
        super(number, value);
        this.paid = false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String creditOrderDetails = new String();
        creditOrderDetails += super.toString();
        creditOrderDetails += String.format("%30s", this.paid.toString());
        return creditOrderDetails;
    }

    public void pay() {
        this.paid = true;
    }

    public void refund() {
        if (this.paid) {
            this.refunded = true;
        }
    }

    // self assessment 7 add code here
}
```

For some reason that I can't fathom, `payOrder` doesn't work, and the order always comes back unpaid, while `deliverOrder` and `refundOrder` work fine. By the way, is there some way I can get it to immediately display the orders in their updated state, because for some reason when I refund an order or mark it delivered, I have to run `displayOrder` to see the updated order. Also, does anyone know what the pale green highlighting in NetBeans means? I keep seeing it, but can't seem to find any key on the web. TIA.

Comment: "doesn't work". Could you be more specific about that?

Comment: why do you repeat 'Boolean paid' in your CreditOrder class?

Comment: @Stultuske - sorry if that's unclear. When I select option 4 to run `payOrder`, the order always come back with 'order paid' set to 'false'. OTOH when I select other options to mark an orders as delivered or refunded, they will come back with 'order delivered' or 'order refunded' set to 'true'. I could add a screenshot if it's still unclear.

Comment: @Stultuske - I've no idea why 'Boolean paid' was repeated, but that looks to have fixed it; many thanks! If you wanted to add that as a reply to the post I'll be happy to mark it as the solution.

Comment: ok, I'll add an answer about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are somewhat mixing variables on the hierarchical path:

Your structure is as follows:

[Abstract]class Order

- class CashOrder
- class CreditOrder

The next variables are declared in your Order class:

```
private Integer number;
protected Integer value;
private Boolean delivered;
protected Boolean paid;
protected Boolean refunded;
```

and in CreditOrder, you have this:

```
private Boolean paid;
```

Even though CreditOrder already has a Boolean paid, which it inherits from the Order class.
So, if you call setPaid(boolean paid) on a CreditOrder, you set the local variable that hides the paid in the Order class.

But, when you call the toString on the Order, which is what you do when you print, you are looking at the value of the paid Boolean in your Order class.

If you want to fix your issue, remove the

```
private Boolean paid;
```

line from the CreditOrder class, this way, you will modify the right variable.

Comment: Great, thanks. Not sure why I missed that, but there we are.